# How can I open multiple files to copy data into a master workbook in new tab?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master Excel file that needs to inherit data from .csv files.

When I run the VBA, it will pop up the file explorer, let me select multiple files and loop over them and create new sheets.

When I try to copy the data into the sheet that it created, it gives me a type mismatch error.

```
Sub OpenLMSFiles()

Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim FileChosen As Integer
Dim FileName As String
Dim tempWB As Workbook
Dim i As Integer

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

fd.InitialFileName = "Libraries\Documents"
fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
fd.AllowMultiSelect = True

FileChosen = fd.Show
If FileChosen = -1 Then
    For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
        Set tempWB = Workbooks.Open(fd.SelectedItems(i))
        Call ReadDataFromSourceFile(tempWB)
    Next i
End If
End Sub


Private Sub ReadDataFromSourceFile(src As Workbook)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

Workbooks(src).Worksheets(src.ActiveSheet).Range("A1:Z500").Copy _
Workbooks(ThisWorkbook).Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet).Range("A1:Z500")

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use `activesheet` - specify a sheet name or index, and you can't have an activesheet in two files (I think?). It would be `thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1").range("A1:Z500")`.

Comment: Perhaps better to have sheet parameters for your sub rather than a workbook.

Comment: Thanks SJR, The issue is I can't guarantee that it will be "sheet1". The assumption I'm making is the user will open at least 3 files and so as the files open, the sheets increase. So i'm wanting to open a workbook, copy the contents into a new sheet, and then close the first workbook I just opened, then do it again on the next workbook until the loop ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error is the way you are referencing workbooks and worksheets, which are collections that take index arguments (integer or string). For example you can reference a workbook as `Workbooks(1)` (bad idea) or `Workbooks("FileName.xlsx")` (better). Similarly use `Sheets(1)` or `Sheets("SheetName")`.

`src` is a `Workbook` -> simply use `src.Sheets()`. Because csv files have only 1 worksheet it is safe to use `src.Worksheets(1)` (`Sheets` and `Worksheets` are equivalent).

Anyway, here is a working code. I rearranged the code as I think `ReadDataFromSourceFile` should encapsulate opening and closing the csv file as well as reading data from it (only an opinion)

```
Sub ImportLMSFiles()

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim FileChosen As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    fd.InitialFileName = "Libraries\Documents"
    fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True

    FileChosen = fd.Show
    If FileChosen = -1 Then
        For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
            Call ReadDataFromSourceFile(fd.SelectedItems(i))
        Next i
    End If
    
End Sub


Private Sub ReadDataFromSourceFile(sSrcFilename As String)
    ' Validate the name
    If Right(sSrcFilename, 4) <> ".csv" Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim shtDest As Worksheet: Set shtDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook: Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(sSrcFilename)

    ' csv files have only 1 sheet
    ' UsedRange is exactly what it sounds like
    With wbSrc.Sheets(1)
        .UsedRange.Copy shtDest.Range(.UsedRange.Address)

        ' if you want to rename the new sheet
        ' Bug: another sheet might have the same name -> u need check for that
        ' Here I'm just ducking it: name not changed
        On Error Resume Next
        shtDest.Name = .Name
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    wbSrc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes complete sense. Code worked perfectly.