# Fill textbox with selected items in filemanager

Tags: excel, vba, filenames, basic

I would like to write a program in VBA.
I would like a window to pop up when the program starts, where I can bring up the file manager with a button and the elements what are (multiple)selected here, would be placed in a textbox under each other and excel would open them all at once.

Now I finished the useform with one button and one textbox, and have a code for the button, to open the file manager and enabled the multiselect. Whats next? Anybody can help me?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim fldlg As FileDialog
Set fldlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With fldlg
    
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Find"
    .InitialFileName = "C:\"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xls,*.xlsx"
End With
rv = fldlg.Show
If rv Then
    MsgBox fldlg.SelectedItems(1)

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To open all the files (or build a string listing them all), you need to cycle through the SelectedItems collection and use each in turn:

```
Dim fldlg As FileDialog
Set fldlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

Dim strItems
With fldlg
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Find"
        .InitialFileName = "C:\"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xls,*.xlsx"
    rv = .Show
    If rv Then
    
        'create a string of text for output using MsgBox
        For Each SelectedItem In .SelectedItems
            strItems = strItems & SelectedItem & Chr(13)
        Next
        
        'display string
        MsgBox strItems
        
        'open the files
        For Each SelectedItem In .SelectedItems
            Workbooks.Open SelectedItem
        Next
        
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! But, I want open the files in the opened .xlsx file where the program is running. I try to define this:
Workbooks.Open SelectedItem "C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\thisexcel.xlsx"
But its not working. Whats the problem? So I woud like to open all selected items in excel, every file in a new sheet

Comment: _So I woud like to open all selected items in excel, every file in a new sheet_ That is not possible. You cannot open a workbook which can contain several sheets in a new sheet.

Comment: Do you mean you have a list of files in a table on the current spreadsheet, and at the click of a button the macro reads that list and opens each file? That would be a simple task. However, if you want to open a collection of files, selected by the user *into one sheet* - that would be a much more complicated task - although it has been answered on this site elsewhere.

Comment: Nope. I want to open the selected excel files in a sheets. One excel one sheet, another one is a new sheet beside each other

Comment: So.. something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060536  ?